# Using relative URI as XmlDataProvider's Source

Tags: .net, uri, xmldataprovider

Is it possible to use a relative URI when setting the `Source` property on an `XmlDataProvider` object in .NET? I get the following exception:

```
IOException:System.IO.IOException: Cannot locate resource 'configuration.xml'.
```

When I set the `Source` property using an absolute URI, everything works as expected:

```
provider.Source = new Uri(@"C:\bin\Configuration.xml", UriKind.Absolute);
```

However when I try using a relative URI I get the exception:

```
provider.Source = new Uri(@"Configuration.xml", UriKind.Relative);
```

My assemblies are all located in the same directory as the configuration file. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
FileInfo file = new FileInfo("configuration.xml");
provider.Source = new System.Uri(file.FullName);

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the following solves both document loading and using relative source path issues. Using a XmlDataProvider, which is defined in xaml, leaving the Source empty (should be possible in code too) :

```
<Window.Resources>
<XmlDataProvider 
    x:Name="myDP"
    x:Key="MyData"
    Source=""
    XPath="/RootElement/Element"
    IsAsynchronous="False"
    IsInitialLoadEnabled="True"                         
    debug:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel="High"  /> </Window.Resources>
```

The data provider automatically loads the document once the source is set. Here's the code :

```
    m_DataProvider = this.FindResource("MyData") as XmlDataProvider;
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo("MyXmlFile.xml");

    m_DataProvider.Document = new XmlDocument();
    m_DataProvider.Source = new Uri(file.FullName);
```