# Saving User Config data to XML and Relative URI error

Tags: wpf, vb.net, uri, config

Good evening,

I am working on a program where some application config info is stored in a Userconfig.xml file.  I am loading the file as an XMLDataProvider in the XAML via relative URI:

```
<XmlDataProvider x:Name="UserConfigDataSource" x:Key="UserConfigDataSource" Source="UserConfig.xml" d:IsDataSource="True"/>
```

I have a number of items throughout bound to elements in the document and an event handler that saves to the XMLDataProvider:

```
Private Sub SaveConfig(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e as System.EventArgs)
    'TODO: Add event handler implementation here

    Dim SavePath As String = UserConfigDataSource.Source.LocalPath.ToString
    Dim XMLDoc = UserConfigDataSource.Document
    UserConfigDataSource.Document.Save(SavePath)
End Sub
```

When this executes I get the error "This operation is not supported for a relative URI".  Is there a good way to produce an absolute URI (aside from getting the assembly executing location and trimming the executable filename from the end)?  I expected this to be a somewhat simple procedure.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used the suggestion [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059916/using-relative-uri-as-xmldataproviders-source)

```
FileInfo config= new FileInfo("configuration.xml"); 
provider.Source = new System.Uri(config.FullName);
```

All worked well.

Cory

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the exact value of SavePath in the debugger ? As it was a URI in XAML, it may have a syntax not understood by XmlDocument.Save.
You could also try AbsoluteUri.ToString

Comment: Yeah, it returns Nothing.  Also UserConfigDataSource (which is an XMLProvider object) Source.LocalPath property returns the exception.  It just doesn't like the fact that I am calling something relative to the install path I am guessing.

Cory

Comment: Just saw this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059916/using-relative-uri-as-xmldataproviders-source .  Will check it out tomorrow or Monday.

Cory